# Automatic focusing if the new window in x11

Tags: c, window, x11, xlib

When I create a new window using x11 and XCreateSimpleWindow, I observe that the keyboard focus automatically goes onto this new window. Is there any method to prevent this auto-focusing ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a function of your window manager.  Changing this behaviour varies from one WM to another.  Most, if not all, will behave as you describe with new windows.  If you are just wanting to do this with a specific new window that you are creating, you could try setting the type to something that wouldn't normally get focus (like _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_TOOLTIP) but then you may get no decorations or anything either.  You could also look at what window currently has the keyboard focus before mapping, and then change it back after you map it.  There may be other solutions, depending on exactly what you are looking to do.